# How can I use GNU Parallel with host groups?

Tags: gnu-parallel

How can I maintain a list of remote hosts to run GNU Parallel commands on, without having to specify the servers manually?

Preferably, I can have a few different groups/files with machine names/addresses in them and run GNU Parallel commands on any of those groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--slf FILE` option to specify a file with hostnames in it. If the normal command line argument looks like `-S $SERVER1,$SERVER2,$SERVER3`, your file can look like:

```
$SERVER1,$SERVER2
$SERVER3
```

That is, you can have the same comma separated list on one line, each server on a new line or a mix between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at `--hostgroups` from version 20141122. It should cover most hostgroup situations.